# Api to filter the conversations, and retrieve the data like last last unread message index of all those filtered conversations

Tags: twilio, twilio-conversations

I'm using Twilio conversations api to create conversation between seller and admin also between seller and buyer. so now i want to retrieve all the conversations between seller and admin and also their unread msg count and also the conversations should be in the order of latest activity.Is there any api to retrieve the same.

I have read the twilio docs and i dint find any api to do the same . so can i get some help in finding the right api to use for my problem statement.